# Secure way to enabling desktop clients to communicated to webapp

Tags: api, authentication

Down the road I'd like to build a Desktop client, iPhone app, etc to interact with the web app I'm working on right now. I'm currently working on adding the authenitcation layer to the app and I'm trying to keep these future plans in mind. What is the best way to set this up. I've been reading up on securing an API and a lot of what I've read recommends using a  public and private key. Is this the right approach to use? It seems to me like this isn't the correct approach since the first thing the user will do is login at which point I'd have to send the private key to the app which doesn't seem very private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public and Private key is the correct approach. Your app or server *never* send their private keys. Only the public keys are exposed. The process is as follows:

1. Your app uses the `server's public`
   key to encrypt the data and sends it
2. The only way the data can be
   decrypted is by using the `server's private` key and so only the server can read it.
3. Server uses `app's public` key to encrypt data and sends
4. The only way that data can be decrypted is by using the `app's private` key and so only the app can read it.

I suggest you read more about how Public-Private key communication works. I will try to provide a link to a good primer.

Edit: [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) on the matter is actually quite good.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the info. The steps you laid out helped clarify things and I'll go ahead and read up on the exact process more.